# Problem with opning the page (License agreement page)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am very confused. How can display agreement page only once in time of use of application.I don't how can i explain this .But I am trying to explain this .
I am creating the application in which i have the  agreement page which has the two button 
(1)Button name is Accept
(2)Button name is Reject

If user click the Accept button application enter into the next page But when the user click on the Reject button application exit out from the application .
But the twist is here 
If user run this application first time he see the agreement page and if user accept this agreement then only then after he move farther .**But when user use this application again and again he must not see the agreement page again and again if he already accept the agreement.** 
Please help me out how can i solve this I am very confused. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOU CAN  Apply the Agreement Page through The Alter View

and

If User Accept the  Agreement  than You Store The Value of Agreed(Possibly Bollean) in the plist file(possibly from document directory of the app) 
  than each time  you  can check it

[image]

CODE FOR TO  NOT TO Display Agreement If it is accepted For once

add one plist file in to  resource folder
  Add one boolean variable  in plist Set Value  AS UNCHECKED(REJECTED STATE)

//Copy the plist to document directory

```
-(void)CopyPlistTODocument
  {

BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if (success) return;
// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}

}

//NOW Call Another method that  read data form plist of document directory
      -(void)desclaimer
     {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path =[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"setting.plist"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path]; 
BOOL *temp=[plist valueForKey:@"Agreement"];
 //if the value of the temp got YES That Agreed earlier so no need to agreed again
if ([temp isEqualToString:@"NO"]) 
{
    //Show Alert View From Here  And call Method  Accept() on the button           pressed event of the accept  button
}
  }
 //Now From  Button Pressed Event Of The Accept Here is the Accept method
  -(void)Accept
    {
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path =[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path]; 
[plist setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"Agreement"]; 
    //now every time the value read from here has agreed state so alert view will not get called
[plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; 

   }
```

Comment: how can i do this can you explain me more

Comment: where should i write this code.And can you me explain more for better understanding

Comment: you need to write this code from  app-did-finish-launching method in app delegate  class

Comment: can you give me hint how to implement this methods  delegate class.Can i call like this if ([temp isEqualToString:@"NO"]) 
{//this my EULA class
    EULA *an = [[EULA alloc]init];[self.navigationcontroller pushviewController:an animated:YES];
}

Comment: can you explain actaully what u did?

Comment: @nikhil look above i make changes how I use your code .But it was not work Where I am getting wrong

Comment: But i think you not able to see the changes .How can a send you what i did

Comment: I call the desclaimer method in delegate .m in fileapplicationDidFinishLaunching like this [self performSelector:@selector(desclaimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:.03];

Comment: @Nikhil PLease check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290433/eula-form-is-not-working-in-iphone i send the same this .How i use your code .I ask this question through my friends Stack_ID.Where go wrong.

Comment: @user6271:down load source code from the URL==>http://www.4shared.com/file/rxPVb3pN/Untitled.html

Comment: This link is block over here can you send this through other source link like github

Comment: https://github.com/nikhildhamsaniya/give-disclaimer-notice-before-entering-to-specific--page-

Comment: Thank you very much nikhil it's working .Can i display page on place of UIAlertView .

Comment: @Ajay: Hi how did you manage your EULA. I have also done above coding. I want to show 6pages of EULA but I am unable to take any controller instead of UIAlertView. Can you explain me here on link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060310/how-to-add-textview-320460-in-uialertview-iphone

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to put this license agreement when you are sending your app to iTunes Connect , it have a place specially for that.

so if the user disagree he will not install the app in the first place

Check "EULA" part of "iTunesConnect DeveloperGuide" page 52

hope it helped you.

Comment: can you send me link how to use EULA

Comment: there is nothing to use.
did you submit an app before to app store ?? if yes then this is only a field you fill during submitting the app.

if no then you should read the pdf i sent you about submitting apps through iTunes Connect