# How to add TextView 320*460 in UIAlertView iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I am showing EULA at the start with UIAlertView having Accept button. I have successfully followed answer on [Problem with opning the page (License agreement page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261655/problem-with-opning-the-page-license-agreement-page) link.

I just want to show 6 pages of EULA at the start but I am unable to show the full size textview/scrollview having EULA content in Alertview. Can anyone suggest me the proper way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you fit such a huge text view into an alert view in the first place? Just dump the text into the alert view and let it render its own way, or use a modal view controller.

Comment: If we can show tableview in alertView...then why not Textview with scrollable??

Comment: Why do you need to when the alert view provides its own implementation? Like I said, just set the alert view's message to your text and it will handle it.

Comment: actually I tried this but the EULA content is very larg. It was showing many errors on lines where ",.' etc symbols are present.

Comment: You should create your own custom AlertView.

Comment: @boltClock : If I insert the Modelview controller then what will be the logic code. By taking another controller with UITextView and accept,reject button app is crashing..

Answer (score 2):

You can make alertView of any size and add custom TextView of any size. Use code snippiest

```
- (void) doAlertViewWithTextView {

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

alert.title = nil;
alert.message = nil;
alert.delegate = self;
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:nil];

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:alert.bounds];
textView.text = @"This is what i am trying to add in alertView.\nHappy New Year Farmers! The new Winter Fantasy Limited Edition Items have arrived! Enchant your orchard with a Icy Peach Tree, and be the first farmer among your friends to have the Frosty Fairy Horse. Don't forget that the Mystery Game has been refreshed with a new Winter Fantasy Animal theme! ";
textView.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textView.editable = NO;
[alert addSubview:textView];
[textView release];

[alert show];
[alert release];
```

}

But by making the size of alertView equal to size of whole iPhone screen you will lose cancel button.

Also use this delegate method.

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {

[alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];}
```

Comment: yes its working but I want to show Accept & Reject button at the below of textView. right now its not looking good. any suggestion for alert and Textview screensize so that it will fit as I need...

Comment: for this purpose you have to reduce size of textView or make a class inherited from alertView and make custom buttons.

Comment: Can't see the textview on iOS8 iPad