# Adding TextView to UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uialertview

when I add textview on alertview, the scollview is shown on top and behind of it the text is drawn,how to overcome this problem. Here is the code

question updated:

If the set textView.editable = NO; it work's fine but in my case i need to type the text in textview.

```
 UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 50)];

    [textView setText:@"lashdasjh asdasjdas asdlajsdl adsjajadsd aslj daj sdjasdjasjdlasjd as dlasj d"];

    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Type Your Message" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Send",nil];

    av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;

    [av addSubview:textView];

    [av show];
```

[image]   [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060310/how-to-add-textview-320460-in-uialertview-iphone

Comment: I would think 12 would be a larger number

Comment: +1 for attention, seems weird.

Comment: check this tutorial. http://ddchettige.blogspot.com/2012/06/1.html

Answer (score 4):

Resolved mySelf.  Remove the `@"\n\n\n\n\n\n"` in message and add `@"\n\n\n\n\n\n"` in title

[image]

Comment: add screen shots in u r answer

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work anymore on IOS7, but using https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview will help you get it done pretty well

Answer (score -1):

replace your code with this code its work fine.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 100)];

UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Type Your Message" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Send",nil];

av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;

[av addSubview:textView];

[av show];
```