# TextField on AlertView not showing on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios7, uialertview

Before iOS7 I could add a `UITextField` (text input field) to my `UIAlertView` by using this code.

```
UITextField *txtNewPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:secondTextFldRect];

        txtNewPassword.delegate     = self;
        txtNewPassword.text         = @"";
        txtNewPassword.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        txtNewPassword.borderStyle      = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        txtNewPassword.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        txtNewPassword.tag              = kNewPasswordTxtFldTag;
        [txtNewPassword setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [txtNewPassword setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
        [txtNewPassword setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
        [txtNewPassword setPlaceholder:@"New password"];
        [txtNewPassword setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [txtNewPassword setSecureTextEntry:YES];
        [alert addSubview:txtNewPassword];
        [txtNewPassword release];
```

After the update to iOS7 it stopped working - my text fields are no longer showing up. What's the advised way of updating my code?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060310/how-to-add-textview-320460-in-uialertview-iphone

Comment: specify your problem. working with Xcode 5 with iOS7 then whats the problem dude?

Answer (score 7):

You want to use the "new" (iOS 5) methods of UIAlertView that provide you with a UITextField. [`alertViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertView/alertViewStyle) and [`textFieldAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/textFieldAtIndex:)

Which reduces your code to this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] ...];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;

UITextField *txtNewPassword = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];

txtNewPassword.delegate     = self;
txtNewPassword.text         = @"";
txtNewPassword.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txtNewPassword.tag              = kNewPasswordTxtFldTag;
[txtNewPassword setPlaceholder:@"New password"];
```

Your code does not work on iOS7 because adding subViews to UIAlertView [was never allowed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2). The view hierarchy has always been private. Apple started to enforce this restriction.

If you want a customized UIAlertView you have to write your own. Subclass UIView and make it look like UIAlertView.

Answer (score 7):

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
dialog.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[dialog setTitle:@"Your Title"];
[dialog setMessage:@"your message"];

[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];


UITextField *_UITextField  = [dialog textFieldAtIndex:0];
_UITextField.placeholder = @"Placeholder";
_UITextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
[dialog show];

//uialertview delegate method
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==1)//OK button 
    {
        //do ur stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Matthias Bauch, you don't need to add a textfield to the alert view, instead, use the `UIAlertView` property `alertViewStyle`. It accepts values defined in the enum [`UIAlertViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIAlertViewStyle)

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIAlertViewStyle) {
    UIAlertViewStyleDefault = 0,
    UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput, // Secure text input
    UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput,  // Plain text input
    UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput // Two text fields, one for username and other for password
};
```

In your case, to use this follow this code.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter password"
                                                  message:nil
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
[alert show];
```

To validate the input, lets say password entered must be minimum 6 characters, implement this delegate method,

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    if( [inputText length] >= 6 )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

To get the user input

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Login"])
    {
        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Password: %@", password.text);
    }
}
```

`UIAlertView` has a private view hierarchy and it is recommended to use it as-is without modification. Hence `addSubview:` to a alert view will have no effect on its view.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertView with a UITextField..

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(14, 45, 255, 23);
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
textField.placeholder = @"Name";
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; // has 'x' button to the right
[alertView addSubview:textField];

[alertView show];
```

Courtesy http://kshitizghimire.com.np/uitextfield-in-uialertview/